# Low level laser therapy for pain

Tags: alternative-medicine

My dad just visited the chiropractor for leg pain. He was given this "laser" device that is supposed to relieve pain. I think the product is called B Laser (Low Level Laser Therapy).

Right away I am skeptical that a laser can be used to treat pain. Is this a scam?

Comment: This question lacks a notable reference ([e.g?](http://www.amazon.com/B-cure-Therapy-Injuries-Revolutionary-Approved/dp/B008MYTOEE))

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The evidence for therapeutic effects of very low powered lasers is weak and there is history of deliberate deception by makers of these devices.

It is notable that laser pointers can be bought for $5 but laser therapy devices can cost $750.

See [*A Skeptical Look at Low Level Laser Therapy* by Stephen Barrett, M.D.](http://www.devicewatch.org/reports/lllt.shtml)

> the bottom line appears to be that LLLT devices may bring about temporary relief of some types of pain, but there's no reason to believe that they will influence the course of any ailment or are more effective than other forms of heat delivery.

---

Other references

- [Role of Low-Level Laser Therapy in Neurorehabilitation](http://www.ncbi.nlm.nih.gov/pmc/articles/PMC3065857/)
- [Efficacy Of Low-Level Laser Therapy In The Treatment Of Neck Pain](http://www.medicalnewstoday.com/articles/170796.php)

---

A lot of people find paracetamol effective against pain and a microwaved bag of wheat an effective and low cost method of [using heat to temporarily relieve pain](http://www.theguardian.com/science/2006/jul/05/health.society).

Comment: Laser pointers and laser therapy devices are not guaranteed to work on the same frequency, nor they have the same power/functionality. Please expand the analogy, or it is as good as "A pen and a syringe are fundamentally an empty plastic tube, with some fluid inside, it is notable that a syringe costs 2$ but a pen costs 0.05$".